# jQuery slideUp and slideDown but with fadeOut and fadeIn?

Tags: jquery

i have done an Accordion style jQuery function which works lovely, but would like to add to it fadeOut and FadeIn here is the part of the code:

```
$('.product-accordion-trigger').click(function(){
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.product-accordion-trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Im wanting to it fadeOut then slideUp and then again fadeOut on slideDown

Your time and help is much appriciated :)

Thanks

**UPDATED - Working Version**

I managed to get it all working great and the solution was as follows:

```
$('.product-accordion-trigger').click(function(){
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            $('.product-accordion-trigger').removeClass('active').next().animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 0 });
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 1 });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks to lolwut for the original kick start! hope this helps anyone else with the same problem

Comment: Please post your solution below as a complete answer and then "accept" your own answer.

Comment: Ooooops! I see below that, even though he posted the answer and accepted it, his reputation (1) has not increased.

Comment: @zequinha-bsb, That is the accepted procedure when you solve your own problems.  This is the best way to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get it working as needed with the following. Hope it helps anyone else looking for a similar solution!

```
$('.product-accordion-trigger').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
        $('.product-accordion-trigger')
            .removeClass('active').next()
            .animate({ height: 'hide', opacity: 0 });

        $(this).toggleClass('active').next()
            .animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 1 });
    }
    return false;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings
>   'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'.

Answer (score 1):

You use callbacks like this:

```
$('.product-accordion-trigger').click(function(){
    if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
        $('.product-accordion-trigger').removeClass('active').next().animate({ width: 'hide', opacity: 0 }, function()
        {
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().animate({ width: 'show', opacity: 1 });
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```