# How to slide and fade a div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slideup, fadeout

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734554/jquery-fadeout-then-slideup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022764/jquery-slideup-and-slidedown-but-with-fadeout-and-fadein) but It did not help.
I have a news ticker. the list with fixed height has items which go up and appends to end of list.

EDITED : **JUST ONE ITEM SHOWN AT A TIME and by first item sliding up and fading out the next one slides up and fades in**

```
<ul id="ticker">
    <li>
        Sample note 1
    </li>
    <li>
        Sample note 2
    </li>
    <li>
        Sample note 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUP( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 2000);
```

I want to configure this so not only it slides Up but also fades Out and at the bottom it fades In with sliding effect.
I know I should use animate effect. I tried it so many times but none of them worked. please help me on this.
thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I will do my best, however I am a newbie

Comment: Check this question for more details on your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524612/how-to-run-jquery-fadein-and-slidedown-simultaneously

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: FadeOut then SlideUp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734554/jquery-fadeout-then-slideup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my solution at http://jsfiddle.net/zLe2B/19/

html:

```
<ul id="ticker">
    <li>
        <span>Sample note 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Sample note 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Sample note 3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    function tick(timeout){
        var first = $('#ticker li:first');
        var next = first.next();

        first.children('span').fadeOut(timeout);
        first.slideUp(timeout, function () {      
             first.appendTo($('#ticker'));                
        });

        next.slideDown(timeout);
        next.children('span').hide().fadeIn(timeout);
    }
    setInterval(function(){tick(1000)}, 2000);
});​
```

​
css:

```
ul, li, span {
    display: block
}

#ticker li {
    height: 20px;
}

#ticker {
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but this is not exactly what is needed. only one item must be shown and first item should fadeOut with slideup and the next item should fadeIn with slideUp

Comment: Thanks. this is so close to what I wanted and solved long way of my problem.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach is:

```
function ticker(el, duration) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        el = typeof el === 'object' ? el : $(el);
        duration = duration || 500;
        $(el).find('li').first().slideUp(duration, function() {
            $(this)
                .insertAfter($(this).nextAll('li').last())
                .fadeIn(duration, function(){
                    ticker(el, duration);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

You can call this with a jQuery object:

```
ticker($('#ticker'));​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5y3Ux/).

Or using a plain DOM node, with a specified duration (in milliseconds):

```
ticker(document.getElementById('ticker'), 300);​​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5y3Ux/1/).

In response to the comment left by the OP (in comments, below):

> This solution slides up the first item and fades in the last one. but I want fade+slide at both first and next items. the list is styled so just one item displayed at a time.

I offer this, using `animate()` to animate the height/opacity of the list elements:

```
function ticker(el, duration) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        el = typeof el === 'object' ? el : $(el);
        duration = duration || 500;
        var first = el.find('li').first(),
            last = first.nextAll().last(),
            h = last.height();
        first.animate({
            height: 0,
            opacity: 0
        }, duration, function() {
            $(this).insertAfter(last).animate({
                height: h,
                opacity: 1
            }, duration, function() {
                ticker(el, duration);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5y3Ux/2/).

**Edited** following clarification from OP, to the following:

```
function ticker(el, duration) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        el = typeof el === 'object' ? el : $(el);
        duration = duration || 500;
        var lis = el.find('li').css('display', 'none');

        lis.first().fadeIn(duration, function(){
            $(this).slideUp(duration, function(){
                $(this).insertAfter(lis.last());
                ticker(el, duration);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5y3Ux/3/).

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Comment: that's a smart solution +1

Comment: it seems the first item not fadeout, it just slide up

Comment: Thanks alot but it does not have fadeOut effect with slideUp for the first list item. it just hase slideUp alone

Comment: This solution slides up the first item and fades in the last one. but I want fade+slide at both first and next items. the list is styled so just one item displayed at a time.

Comment: @namkha87 thanks, but that is not exactly what I meant. please read my comment on your solution

Comment: @Pedar: you want to have *one* visible item at a time? Which then fades out, and the next item fades in? (I'm a little slow, this morning...)

Comment: yes. this is a ticker which shows only one item (one news title) at a time. the first item should go up and fade while the next item should come up with fadeIn effect.